# Partial View in MVC with its own Model and Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am making a Partial view with its own controller and Model I also want to pass some data when I am loading the patial view here is my codes could you please check them and let me know what is wrong?

```
//Patial HTML Code
@model *******.Model.ViewModels.EmailViewModel

<fieldset class="emailForm_fn">
    <div class="left label width100">
        From</div>
    <div class="left">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.From, new { @class = "width300" })
    </div>   
</fieldset>


//Patial Contyroller Code
 public partial class EmailController : Controller
{
public ActionResult Initialize(string from)
        {
            var viewModel = new EmailViewModel()
            {
                Attachment = "",
                BCC = "",
                CC = "",
                Content = "",
                From = from,
                Subject = "",
                To = ""
            };
            return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_email.cshtml",viewModel);
        }
}


//Codes for loading loading

@{ Html.RenderAction("Initialize", "Email", new { from = "Brezvani@ucm.com.au" }); }
```

Comment: You aren't loading the data in your view. Typically you would use @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.From, new { .... })

Comment: @Ganesh Model binding is case-insensitive actually.

Comment: you do understand that partial views have absolutely nothing to do with partial classes, right?